# How to parse a CSV file in which the first character of each line is a comma?

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I have a c# CSV parser that has been working very well for months. It uses [FileHelpers.CsvEngine](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_CsvEngine_CsvToDataTable_1.htm) to do the heavy lifting. My system must receive 3rd-party CSV files as-is (very difficult to go back to vendors and say "change it"). After months of successful CSV parsing, I'm now encountering several large files in which every line begins with a comma. And the CSV truly uses comma-separated values (not tabs, spaces, etc).

Here is the line that blows up:

```
DataTable dt = CsvEngine.CsvToDataTable(@"c:\somefile.csv", ',');
```

And here is the error:

> The string '' not is a valid .NET identifier

Here are a few sample rows from the CSV (the first row is the header):

```
,ORG_NO,ORG_REV_NO,ZMODEL,Q_DATE
,7,1,02-8FD10            ,7/21/2009 9:33
,7,1,02-8FD14            ,7/21/2009 9:33
,7,1,02-8FD15            ,7/21/2009 9:33
,7,1,02-8FD18            ,7/21/2009 9:33
```

Observe that the first character of each line is a comma, and that seems to be choking the parser.

As a last resort I can loop the file, remove the first char, and then proceed to parse - but is there a more elegant/straightforward way to handle this? I'd like an approach that just handles it rather than having to peek into each CSV before parsing it, see if the first char is a comma, then take an alternate (and expensive) comma-removal code path if so.

Any ideas?

Comment: CSVs are allowed to start with a comma. I suspect the problem is in your header; `CsvToDataTable` is [trying to create a field without a name](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_CsvEngine_CsvToDataTable_1.htm). Try adding a dummy field name before the first comma in the header.

Comment: Yes that solved it. Thank you Dour.